# required table for Laravel 5 Authentication

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel's auth features, and as it is said in the documents I should have a "users" table in my app so that I can use this feature, but instead of "users" table I got a "user" table.
I changed the $table property of my  User model, and also changed the table property of my Auth config file:
'table' => 'user'
but still got this error upon registration:
QueryException in Connection.php line 620:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = sth@yahoo.com)

Comment: Also add `protected $table = 'user';` in your `User Model`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a different table name for your models you need to define them. In your case you should have

```
 protected $table = 'user';
```

in your User model like this.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user';
}
```